# get more than one element with DOM parser php

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I want to use php and Simple HTML DOM parser to analyze a page.

The HTML Markup are the following:

```
<div class="question">
    <b>My-title1</b><br />
    <label class="false"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="0" />1. <span >text-1</span></label><br />
    <label class="true"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="1" />2. <span >text-2</span></label><br />
    <label class="false"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="0" />3. <span >text-3</span></label><br />
    <label class="false"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="0" />4. <span >text-4</span></label><br />
</div>
```

Now, I use this code to get `My-title` value:

```
foreach($html->find('b') as $e) 
{
    echo $e->innertext . '<br>';
}
```

But I want more...

I want to get `text-1` to `text-4` and also find and filter which of them has `class=true`

So my final output must be:

```
my-title1
text-1
*text-2
text-3
text-4
my-title2
text-1
text-2
text-3
*text-4
...
```

How can I use this? Is it my way true or I must use another solution to do this?

Comment: i dont see anything with class "item" in that example.

Comment: i edited that, that was my wrong here, my code is true i want just solution for final output, tanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you absolutely need to use another solution to get the values. First off, since you want another set of values, which will encompass the `title` and the `text`, you need to broaden the search, which is to target the parent element `<div class="question">`.

This must be your starting point. From there, obviously you need to loop then process the children. Consider this example:

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
// sample markup
$markup = '
<div class="question">
    <b>My-title1</b><br />
    <label class="false"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="0" />1. <span>text-1</span></label><br />
    <label class="true"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="1" />2. <span>text-2</span></label><br />
    <label class="false"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="0" />3. <span>text-3</span></label><br />
    <label class="false"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="0" />4. <span>text-4</span></label><br />
</div>
<div class="question">
    <b>My-title2</b><br />
    <label class="false"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="0" />1. <span>text-1</span></label><br />
    <label class="false"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="1" />2. <span>text-2</span></label><br />
    <label class="false"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="0" />3. <span>text-3</span></label><br />
    <label class="true"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="0" />4. <span>text-4</span></label><br />
</div>
';

$html = str_get_html($markup);
// get each `question class` parent
foreach($html->find('div[class="question"]') as $question_tag) {
    // get the title
    $title = $question_tag->children(0)->innertext; // title tag child
    echo $title . '<br/>';
    // texts inside span
    foreach($question_tag->find('label input span') as $span) {
        if($span->parent()->class == 'true') {
            echo '*';
        }
        echo $span->innertext . '<br/>';
    }
}
```

Should yield something like this:

```
My-title1
text-1
*text-2
text-3
text-4
My-title2
text-1
text-2
text-3
*text-4
```